# Function end index search in java using regex

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I was using regex to find function start and end stored in string in java. But was unable to get end index.

```
String regexPart1 = "((public)|(private)|(protected)) [a-zA-Z_0-9\\<\\>\\,]+ ";
String regexPart2 = "\\(.*\\) (throws .*)?\\{.*}$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexPart1+"run"+regexPart2);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(toEval);

while (matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(" Found: " + matcher.group());
}
```

With

```
toEval = "public class ClassEval{public static initialize() throws Exception(){System.out.println("Initialize");}public static void run() throws Exception{System.out.println("This should come only")}public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println("Hello");}}";
```

Expected output:

```
Found: public static void run(){System.out.println("This should come only")}
```

Output coming:

```
Found: public static void run(){System.out.println("This should come only")}public static void main(String[] args){System.out.println("Hello");}}
```

Comment: You have a `$` sign at the back, of course it will grab everything till the last character. If you want to look for end of method (`()`), then you need a much more complicated regex.

Answer (score 0):

`*` is a [greedy](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) quantifier, meaning `{.*}` will match everything from the first `{` until the last `}`. Change it to `{.*?}` if you want it to stop at the first `}`. Of course it still won't be able to identify nested braces, but that's a whole other issue.